# M2E-Pro stuck at 0% while product listing

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

I'm trying to list 600 products in Magento M2E-Pro, but the progressbar is stuck at 0% even after 1 hour. Waiting a huge amount of time I can see in the Amazon inventory about 400 of 600 products, while in Magento M2E-Pro all the products are still marked as "Inactive". Very strange behaviour.
What I tryed so far:
Checked the execution time of the PHP on the Server. 
As I work with less amount of products no problems.
Am I missing somthing in the configurations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long research, I found that in the table **m2epro_lock_item** the was an old dataset, which locked the synchronization. I clened this table and it works again :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's put M2E Pro aside for a few moments.

Amazon is a reports based system, which means when products are sent to Amazon, unlike eBay which you'll geta  response back immediately, Amazon accepts the report, then processes it (typically takes 10-15 mins) and then provides a summary report to let you know what worked and what didn't.

So it's highly likely that it will time out in your browser.

So... instead of sending the products up manually, what I would suggest you do is make sure that your synchronization settings are set to list when the products are active (and have stock etc...) and make sure that the cron is enabled for M2EPro (see tutorial 7 [here](http://understandinge.com/magento-tutorial/setting-up-m2epro/)) and then let M2E Pro run in the background.

It won't be instant and expect a time lag of about 30 mins or maybe more.

Hope that helps,

Matt

Comment: You want to say that Amazon is not so fast to import products. I noticed that but why the progressbar is stuck at 0% ? With less amount of products the progressbar reaches the end in a few seconds. I noticed that the ajax request returns ERROR HTTP: 504. Timeout.. So the problem is the ERROR HTTP: 504. I tryed to set to 0 the PHP execution time and the fastcgi_read_timeout in nginx to a bigger value but nothing.